# Backbone - Cannot get model on click using localstorage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I'm trying to setup a little app in backbone where I can add items to a list and, when I click them, they'll be deleted. I've managed to add items to the list but when using model.destroy() nothing happens.

When I console.log the click event on the list models I get:

child {cid: "c0", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}

for any item I click.

Code is below:

Html:

```
<h1>INDEX!</h1>

<form class="add-form">
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <hr />
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>

<h2>LIST STUFF</h2>

<ul class="blah">
{{#each indexCollection}}
  <li class="li-class">{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
//Local Storage
App.Storage.Local = new Backbone.LocalStorage('localIndexList1-backbone');


//Index Model
App.Models.IndexModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  localStorage: App.Storage.Local,
  defualts:{
    name:''
  },
  urlRoot: '/'
});

//Index Collection
App.Collections.IndexCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  localStorage: App.Storage.Local,
  model: App.Models.IndexModel,
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('Collection initialised');
  },
  url: '/'
});

//View for H1 and input form
App.Views.IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  events:{
    'submit .add-form' : 'addNew',
    'click' : 'deleteMe'
  },
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('IndexView initialised');
  },
  addNew: function(ev){
    // ev.preventDefault();
    var submitEntry = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
    var newEntry = new App.Models.IndexModel();
    newEntry.save(submitEntry, {
      success: function(newEntry){
        // router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
        console.log('SUCESSS!!!!!!!!!');
      }
    });
  },
  deleteMe: function(){
    console.log(this.model);
    //Whatever I put here will not work

  } 
});

//View for list
App.Views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('ListView initialised');
  },
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#list').html()),
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    var that = this;
    var indexCollection = new App.Collections.IndexCollection();
    indexCollection.fetch({
      success:function(indexCollection){
        that.$el.html(that.template({indexCollection: indexCollection.toJSON()}));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Would anyone be able to help letting me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you creating one `IndexView` for each of your collection models? You should have an item view, configure its model to be one IndexModel, and move your delete code to that particular view. When you do that, you should also call `remove` in this item view.

This is why something like Backbone.Marionette helps a lot. Just throw in a CollectionView and you're done.

Think of it like this:

1. "list view" -> has a collection
2. "item view" -> has a single model

Anything you need to on the collection level (like adding a new one, re-loading, whatever), do it on your list view. Anything you need on model level (editing, saving, deleting), do it on your item view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that clarifies things for me. So the list view should be rendering all the item views in a list?

Comment: Exactly. Normally you build a specialized type of view, CollectionView, which basically renders another view for every item in the collection. Have a look at https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md